# Write df.value_counts to new file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of cluster labels generated using DBSCAN and I am counting the frequency of the cluster labels. I can print the frequency using `df['cluster_labels'].value_counts()`, but when I go to write this to a new file, I just get the count of clusters but not their corresponding label. How can I write this to write to a new file with the cluster label and the frequency? Below are screenshots and code.

**When printing**:

[image]

**When writing:**

[image]

```
df['cluster_labels'] = cluster_labels
cluster_counts = df['cluster_labels'].value_counts()
print cluster_counts
cluster_counts.to_csv('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_cluster_counts.csv', index=False, header=True)

df_filtered = df[cluster_labels>-1]
cluster_outputs = pd.DataFrame(df_filtered)
#cluster_outputs.to_csv('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 
681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_cluster_outputs.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

**Error passing new headers to file**

[image]

Comment: As the second issue you mentioned at the bottom is not related to the main question, I advise you to remove it from here and ask it in a new question. It's more organized and it's more likely you get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will post a separate question for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using `index=False`. Change the `index=False` to `index=True` in the line

```
cluster_counts.to_csv('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_cluster_counts.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

You can see this in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) of `DataFrame.to_csv`

Comment: Perfect! It wrote both columns, but headers are incorrect. It only wrote cluster label, and assigned it to the frequency column. So, I passed a string of headers 'column_label' and 'frequency' but it returned a value error saying writing 1 cols, but got 2 aliases..

Comment: I passed `count_heads = ['cluster_label','frequency']` to `cluster_counts.to_csv('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_cluster_counts.csv', index=True, header=count_heads)`. I added a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: Read the documentation page carefully. `header` should be True or False. If True then it takes the header from the dataframe.

Comment: The documentation says: 'boolean or list of string, default True', so I attempted to pass a list of headers. Is that not the same?

Comment: You can also pass column names. But if your df has only one column, you need to provide a list of length one. (index does not count as column)

Comment: Ah, okay! I understand what the issue was. I passed the `index_label` argument and a header string, and worked perfectly. Thanks!